# WebSphere portal 8.5 redirecting to home page from custom wab filter

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

Can we redirect to home page or login page from custom filter in WebSphere portal ? When I'm trying to redirect using httpResponse.sendRediect(""), its giving errors saying response already committed and displaying blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing authentication filters like ImplocitLoginFter, ExplicitLoginFilter, SessionTimeoutFilter etc.